# how to parse Json array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I want to parse the json array given below .this is the json i get when inspect.

`0: "Harpic Power Plus Original Liquid Toilet Cleaner"
 1: "HARPIC Powerplus Disinfectant Toilet Cleaner, Original - 1L Liquid Toilet Cleaner"`

but when i use json.parse() i get this error

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
at app.component.ts:42
at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone-evergreen.js:364)
at Object.onInvoke (core.js:41938)
at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone-evergreen.js:363)
at Zone.run (zone-evergreen.js:123)
at zone-evergreen.js:857
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:399)
at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:41916)
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:398)
at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:798)
at zone-evergreen.js:864
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:399)
at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:41916)
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:398)
at Zone.runTask (zone-evergreen.js:167)
at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone-evergreen.js:569)
at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone-evergreen.js:484)
at invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:1621)
at XMLHttpRequest.globalZoneAwareCallback (zone-evergreen.js:1658)
```

Comment: It is not in JSON format

Comment: What's the output of `console.log(yourJsonArray)`? The JSON you have in your post doesn't look like JSON. Sometimes you can parse JSON-like data by using `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(almostJson))`.

Comment: but in postman it shows me {
  "product_name": [
    "Harpic Power Plus Original Liquid Toilet Cleaner", 
    "HARPIC Powerplus Disinfectant Toilet Cleaner, Original - 1L Liquid Toilet Cleaner"]} which is json

Comment: Ok, that looks more like JSON. Still, it might contain weird whitespace characters etc. Have you tried stringifying the JSON before parsing it?

Comment: when i stringify it it shows me the jsn that postman shows but after i parse it shows me the starting json

Comment: Hold on, so initially you've done `JSON.parse('{ "product_name": [ "Harpic Power Plus Original Liquid Toilet Cleaner", "HARPIC Powerplus Disinfectant Toilet Cleaner, Original - 1L Liquid Toilet Cleaner"]}');` and got an array? That's a JS array, not a JSON array. You can access its values using the array keys, e.g. `const foo = JSON.parse('{ "product_name": [ "Harpic Power Plus Original Liquid Toilet Cleaner", "HARPIC Powerplus Disinfectant Toilet Cleaner, Original - 1L Liquid Toilet Cleaner"]}'); console.log(foo.product_name[0]); console.log(foo.product_name[1]);`

Comment: i meant when i stringify the json data i showed in the original question it got the result I got in postman but when i json.parse the stringified json I again get the data that i showed in the original question.Do you understand? or do you want the code? And I thank you for trying to help me so much

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand. There's no JSON data in your original question... It'd be helpful if you could share more or your code.

Comment: I mean this 0: "Harpic Power Plus Original Liquid Toilet Cleaner" 1: "HARPIC Powerplus Disinfectant Toilet Cleaner, Original - 1L Liquid Toilet Cleaner"

Comment: Yes, and that is not JSON. Please show your code.

Comment: your suggestion worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hold on, so initially you've done`JSON.parse('{ "product_name": [ "Harpic Power Plus Original Liquid Toilet Cleaner", "HARPIC Powerplus Disinfectant Toilet Cleaner, Original - 1L Liquid Toilet Cleaner"]}');`and got an array? That's a JS array, not a JSON array. You can access its values using the array keys, e.g.`const foo = JSON.parse('{ "product_name": [ "Harpic Power Plus Original Liquid Toilet Cleaner", "HARPIC Powerplus Disinfectant Toilet Cleaner, Original - 1L Liquid Toilet Cleaner"]}'); console.log(foo.product_name[0]); console.log(foo.product_name[1]);`hope this works

Answer (score -1):

a json formatted of your sample would be like this:

```js
var myJson = {
  first: "Harpic Power Plus Original Liquid Toilet Cleaner",
  second: "HARPIC Powerplus Disinfectant Toilet Cleaner, Original - 1L Liquid Toilet Cleaner"
};

console.log(JSON.stringify(myJson));
```

Comment: this is what I get if  i json.stringify that {"product_name":["Harpic Power Plus Original Liquid Toilet Cleaner","HARPIC Powerplus Disinfectant Toilet Cleaner, Original - 1L Liquid Toilet Cleaner" but i want to get the items in the array